# External HDD for Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: windows, hard-drive

I have a 2TB external USB HDD I would like to use. There is currently no important data stored on the drive - so I am willing to wipe it if necessary. I use different systems - one is a Windows 10 Home, the other Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (GNOME 3). I will never be using both of the systems at the same time. I cannot find a firm, fluent solution to this issue.

What disk format should I use? Will I only need one partition? I can format the disk from either Windows 10 or Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Thank you, all!

Comment: Both Linux and Windows can read and write FAT32 and exFAT effortlessly.

Answer (score 1):

Format it as **NTFS**, the native format of Windows 10, which Ubuntu can read and write, as noted in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions.

Although there are third party drivers to enable Windows to read/write the Ubuntu-native **ext4** partitions, I have had bad luck with those myself and don't recommend them.

Answer (score 0):

Format the external HDD as NTFS format via Windows disk manager. If this is done via Linux (for some reason), the HDD cannot be read by Windows. This format has overall been relatively slow but usable for backups and generic file storage.